# Docker-compose ERROR: No containers to start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Файл docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    webserver:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Создаю сервис: `docker-compose -p my up --no-start`

Смотрю список контейнеров: `docker container ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
99dabcf2b2cf        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   4 seconds ago       Created                                 my_webserver_1_5f7310de9b9a
```

Пробую запустить: `docker-compose start`

```
Starting webserver ... done
ERROR: No containers to start
```

Но работает, если не указывать имя (`-p my`)

Пролистал команды в .bash_history ну вдруг что-то не то ввожу, так нет - те же команды. Вчера работало, сегодня ничего не обновлял.

Версия: `docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306`

Comment: а если `docker-compose -p my start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим документацию:

COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME
Sets the project name. This value is prepended along with the service name to the container on start up. For example, if your project name is myapp and it includes two services db and web, then Compose starts containers named myapp_db_1 and myapp_web_1 respectively.
Setting this is optional. If you do not set this, the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME defaults to the basename of the project directory. See also the -p command-line option.

Делаем выводы:
т.к. создавали контейнер с префиксом "my" (флаг -p), то и запускать, видимо, нужно так же (либо и создавать, и запускать без -p с умолчальным значением).

Comment: Да, понял, получилось, надо указывать имя контейнера, если это имя было указано при создании контейнера. Спасибо большое!